# Conditions for all positive $x$ solved by $\min \bf{x}^T\bf{x}$ $s.t. Ax=b$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I want to find a condition for having all nonnegative $x_i$ in

$\min \bf{x}^T\bf{x}$

$s.t. \bf{Ax}=\bf{b}$

where $\bf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$, $\bf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $\bf{b}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$ and $m<n$.

From a geometric perspective, I can infer that if there exists a closed region formed by the hyperplane $\bf{Ax}=\bf{b}$ and the positive axes, the solutions will be all positive. But it is so abstract that I can't prove it using formulas and theorem.

Comment: Do you need strict positivity, or will nonnegativity do?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you mean by "a condition"? Frankly, there's not going to be a condition that is both (1) general and (2) avoids statements like "there exists a vector [which you must find] satisfying..."

Comment: In fact, the nonnegativity what I need and I will correct my mistake. I mean that if $\bf{A}$ and $\bf{b}$ satisfy some rules, the solutions of the optimization problem will be all nonnegative. Thanks.

Comment: I'm just not seeing that being enough here. "some rules" could be anything, including: "if $AA^T$ is invertible and $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b \geq 0$, then $x\geq 0$". But in fact, that's not particularly interesting, because in that scenario, $x = A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b$. So you're just saying "if the solution is positive, then $x$ is positive" :-)